# Integral of rational function is indeterminate

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I need to integrate the rational function

$$\frac{t^n}{bt+t^2+1}$$

where $n$ is a integer. Of course, it's no problem for *Mathematica* to do this.

```
int = Integrate[t^n/(t^2 + b*t + 1), t] // FullSimplify
```

[image: Mathematica result]

But if I try to set $n$ after the integration, the result is `Indeterminate`.

```
int /. n -> 1
```

> ```
> Indeterminate
> ```

Setting $n$ before the integration, however, leads to a nice expression.

```
Integrate[t^1/(t^2 + b*t + 1), t]
```

[image: this works]

Why is this?

Comment: I noticed it works when you say `int/. n->-1`. This suggests that it is a maths problem to me?

Comment: Curiously, taking the D of the function again brings back the original function. Plotting `Plot3D[int /. {b -> 1}, {t, 0, 3}, {n, -4, 4}]` reveals weird things going on when `n>-1`

Comment: Take a limit instead. A simpler example is `Integrate[x^a, x]` gives `x^(a+1)/(a+1)` which clearly isn't valid for `a == -1`.

Comment: @ChipHurst Limits don't seem to work with this `2F1`.  Any other suggestions?

Comment: Use `SetDelayed`:`int[n_, b_, t_] := Integrate[t^n/(t^2 + b*t + 1), t] //FullSimplify` then `int[#, b, t] & /@ Range[-2, 2]` (change `Range` to fit your needs).

Comment: As this case shows, one cannot really fully dispense of Gradshteyn and Ryzhik just yet. Formula 2.174 in the seventh edition gives a recurrence formula, which when fed to `RSolve[]` yields a solution that still involves ${}_2 F_1$, but is at least usable for integer `n`.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that the two `Hypergeometric2F1` terms each take the value of `ComplexInfinity` when `n=1`.  The resulting difference is necessarily undefined.  If Mathematica substitutes `n->1` before evaluating the integral, it is able to use a more specific integration technique.

This sort of behaviour occurs frequently: Mathematica results that are generically true may fail for specific values - unfortunate if these are the values you want.

Answer (score 3):

To expand on my comment: in Gradshteyn and Ryzhik (the seventh edition, at least), they list [formula 2.174](http://books.google.com/books?hl=en&id=aBgFYxKHUjsC&pg=PA80), which I think is more practical for computational purposes than the direct output of *Mathematica*. Translated into *Mathematica* syntax for the OP's specific case, if we have

```
int[n_] := Integrate[t^n/(t^2 + b t + 1), t]
```

then there is the useful (inhomogeneous) difference equation

```
int[n] == t^(n - 1)/(n - 1) - b int[n - 1] - int[n - 2]
```

This can in fact be fed into either of `RSolve[]` or `DifferenceRoot[]` to yield a useful solution if desired; `RSolve[{int[n] == t^(n - 1)/(n - 1) - b int[n - 1] - int[n - 2], int[0] == (2 ArcTan[(b + 2 t)/Sqrt[4 - b^2]])/Sqrt[4 - b^2], int[1] == -((b ArcTan[(b + 2 t)/Sqrt[4 - b^2]])/Sqrt[4 - b^2]) + 1/2 Log[1 + b t + t^2]}, int[n], n]` will in fact yield a (complicated!) expression involving ${}_2 F_1$ that works for nonnegative integer `n`, and `DifferenceRoot[Function[{int, n}, {int[n] == t^(n - 1)/(n - 1) - b int[n - 1] - int[n - 2], int[0] == (2 ArcTan[(b + 2 t)/Sqrt[4 - b^2]])/Sqrt[4 - b^2], int[1] == -((b ArcTan[(b + 2 t)/Sqrt[4 - b^2]])/Sqrt[4 - b^2]) + 1/2 Log[1 + b t + t^2]}]]` shows that `int[n]` satisfies a *four*-term *homogeneous* difference equation, and is already directly useful besides.